# How to make all render caches update on a configuration override?

Tags: 8, blocks, caching, configuration

**Short version:**

I am using a configuration override to override the site name. Changes are reflected in the HTML title, but not in the system branding block. Drupal keeps serving this block from the render cache.

**Long version:**

I am using a configuration override service that implements ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface, which overrides configs on demand. Slightly simplified, it looks like this:

```
class MyConfigOverride implements ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function loadOverrides($names) {
    $overrides = [];

    if ($override_required) {
      if (in_array('system.site', $names)) {
        $overrides['system.site']['name'] = 'My name';
      }
    }
    return $overrides;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheSuffix() {
    return 'MyConfigOverride';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheableMetadata($name) {
    $metadata = new CacheableMetadata();

    if ($name === 'system.site') {
      $my_entity = MyEntity::Load(1);
      if ($override_required && !empty($my_entity)) {
        // Append entity cache metadata (cache tags and context).
        $metadata->addCacheableDependency($my_entity);
      }
    }
    return $metadata;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function createConfigObject($name, $collection = StorageInterface::DEFAULT_COLLECTION) {
    return NULL;
  }

}
```

However, as soon as this override kicks in, the render cache for the System branding block does not get updated with the new site name. This is because the [SystemBrandingBlock](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/system/src/Plugin/Block/SystemBrandingBlock.php) class does implement `getCacheTags()` in which it merges the system.site cache tags (see below), but it does not implement `getCacheContexts()` (which my module uses since I serve a variation of the page).

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getCacheTags() {
  return Cache::mergeTags(
    parent::getCacheTags(),
    $this->configFactory->get('system.site')->getCacheTags()
  );

}
```

I have tried to overcome this by adding additional 'empty' cache metadata to my class for the cases where the override does not apply.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheableMetadata($name) {
    $metadata = new CacheableMetadata();

    if ($name === 'system.site') {
      $my_entity = MyEntity::Load(1);
      if ($override_required && !empty($my_entity)) {
        // Append entity cache metadata.
        $metadata->addCacheableDependency($my_entity);
      }
      else {
        // Append 'empty' cache metadata.
        $metadata->addCacheContexts(['mycachecontext']);
        $metadata->addCacheTags(['myentity', 'myentity:0']);
      }
    }
    return $metadata;
  }
```

Since the block does not inherit the cache contexts of `system.site` and I do not update or otherwise invalidate any of the provided cache tags ('myentity', 'myentity:0'), the render cache still persists. I can append cache context to the system branding block in a [`hook_block_build_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_build_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter/8.2.x) implementation, but I'd prefer not to implement such specific exceptions as they will never cover all situations.

I am somewhat hoping for a hook to update all renderable elements (blocks?) and append cache contexts to those that inherit cache tags provided by `system.site`. But I am open to alternative solutions as well.

How can I make any block or other entity in the render cache, that is depending on the `system.site` config aware of the config override?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the meantime I have come up with this approach, but I am still open to other solutions.

I have found a solution in a pre_render callback for the blocks, by deconstruction the cacheable metadata, searching it for a `system.site` tag and append my own context and tags (if required).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view_alter().
 */
functionmymodule_block_view_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  $build['#pre_render'][] = 'mymodule_block_view_pre_render';
}

/**
 * #pre_render callback: Sets my module cache tags.
 */
function mymodule_block_view_pre_render(array $build) {
  $cacheable_metadata = CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($build);
  $tags = $cacheable_metadata->getCacheTags();

  if (in_array('config:system.site', $tags)) {
    // Always add a cache context, so we have a variant without overrides as well.
    $cacheable_metadata->addCacheContexts(['mycontext']);

    if ($entity = MyEntity::Load(1)) {
      $cacheable_metadata->addCacheableDependency($entity );
    }
  }

  $cacheable_metadata->applyTo($build);

  return $build;
}
```